# How to "join" sub classes into a super type instance?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, idioms

If I have a function that receives a `Callback` as a parameter, how can I call this function with a "collection" or "group" of sub-class/derived-class of `Callback` such that, based on the received parameter, I can enable/disable certain functionality if received sub-class/derived-class "has" or "matches" the functionality?

For e.g.

```
import kotlin.random.Random

interface Callback

interface FruitsCallback : Callback {
    fun onFruitsDeleted(ignored: Int)
}

interface VegetablesCallback : Callback {
    fun onVegetablesDeleted(ignored: Int)
}

class FruitsStore : FruitsCallback {

    override fun onFruitsDeleted(ignored: Int) {
        throw NotImplementedError()
    }
}

class VegetablesStore : VegetablesCallback {

    override fun onVegetablesDeleted(ignored: Int) {
        throw NotImplementedError()
    }
}

fun delete(callback: Callback) {

    if (callback is FruitsCallback) {
        // Delete 5 fruits
        callback.onFruitsDeleted(5)
    }

    if (callback is VegetablesCallback) {
        // Delete 7 vegetables
        callback.onVegetablesDeleted(7)
    }
}

fun main() {

    val fruitsStore = FruitsStore()
    val vegetablesStore = VegetablesStore()

    val callback: Callback = if (Random.nextBoolean()) {
        fruitsStore + vegetablesStore
    } else fruitsStore

    delete(callback)
}
```

The error is in `main()` method when I try to execute `fruitsStore + vegetablesStore`. This shows a type mismatch problem. Something to do about kotlin's `.plus()`.

But then, how am I able to add following types together when using `coroutines`?

```
val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { context, throwable -> println("$throwable") }
val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + SupervisorJob() + exceptionHandler
```

I want to know how `coroutineContext` is able to receive a group of these types of instances and represent them as one.

I am fairly new to kotlin. Please explain:

- Why I can't do it?
- Why coroutines can do it?
- What is this called?
- How can I do this in above example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coroutine API uses [*operator overloading*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html) to make the `+` operator do something it normally cannot. If you look at the source code, the function of the overloaded plus operator instantiates a new CoroutineContext that has copied values of properties of both of the operands.

In your case, to make this work, you would have to write your own operator function. But trying to implement multiple interfaces conditionally gets very complicated very quickly. In your example, there are only two possible types of Callback, and already that makes for a long function with three branches:

```
operator fun Callback.plus(other: Callback): Callback {
    val callbacks = listOf(this, other)
    return when {
        callbacks.all { it is FruitsCallback } -> object: FruitsCallback {
                override fun onFruitsDeleted(ignored: Int) {
                    callbacks.forEach { (it as FruitsCallback).onFruitsDeleted(ignored) }
                }
            }

        callbacks.all { it is VegetablesCallback } -> object : VegetablesCallback {
                override fun onVegetablesDeleted(ignored: Int) {
                    callbacks.forEach { (it as VegetablesCallback).onVegetablesDeleted(ignored) }
                }
            }

        else -> object: FruitsCallback, VegetablesCallback {
            override fun onFruitsDeleted(ignored: Int) {
                callbacks.forEach { (it as? FruitsCallback)?.onFruitsDeleted(ignored) }
            }

            override fun onVegetablesDeleted(ignored: Int) {
                callbacks.forEach { (it as? VegetablesCallback)?.onVegetablesDeleted(ignored) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If there were a third implementation of Callback, the above function would have seven branches. And there is no enforcement here that you remember to update this function if you add additional implementations.

That said, your version of the `delete()` function's use of `is` is a code smell, failure to utilize polymorphism. In this case, it would be better to add `delete()` as a function in `Callback` and each implementation can define for itself what that should mean.

Comment: Thank you. If these two callbacks can make this overloaded function so complex and lengthy, does this mean that coroutines lib is misusing operator overloading. As if there is something new that can be added to a `coroutineContext`, does this mean they would have to do something that is a code smell? Am I understanding this right? Or is this code example just for reference?

Comment: Also, can you link an article or explanation for `failure to utilise polymorphism`? Something that would tell me of the code smell issue. How do I be able to detect if my code is smelly by polymorphism or other means?

Comment: CoroutineContext is a data object that doesn't perform any functions. Nowhere that I know of does the `is` keyword need to be used with CoroutineContext in the coroutine library. So it is not breaking the design guideline for polymorphism.

Comment: Here's a very succinct explanation. http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31 It's for Java, but `instanceof` in Java is the same as `is` in Kotlin. But this isn't a hard rule, just a sign of a code smell. There are specific cases where polymorphism leads to more complicated code. This article explains that: https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/when-polymorphism-fails

Comment: CoroutineContext is still using polymorphism, but it's doing it by *composition over inheritance*, which is why it's easy to merge two objects.